# Android- Check for install package permissions for API level below 26

Tags: android

So I want to check for android install permission of an app, weather granted or not, in Android API level below 26. This is my code it is working in Android API 26.

```
if(getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()){ //doing someting}
```

From this doc at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#canRequestPackageInstalls()

[image]

I have found out that "canRequestPackageInstalls" has been added from API 26 is there an alternative for this for packages below API 26?

Answer (score 1):

Below API 26, the permission is granted by default. 
Try this:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
        startActivityForResult(newIntent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1);
    } else {
        //do something
    }
} else {
    //do something
}
```